# How to take/release control of output?

Tags: scripts, process

I have two parallel processes running shell script, each will print to stdout from time to time using echo. But sometimes the output may mixed up. Is there a way to take exclusive use of stdout, then release it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly your intention, but I'm assuming you have two processes sending their output to stdout and you want to monitor only one of them at a time.

My suggestion would be to have each process write to its own file instead of stdout.  If you don't want to rewrite your script, you can just have all output for the process redirected using > for only standard output or &> for all output, including stderr.

So you could execute your processes using:

```
$./proc1 &> proc1.out
$./proc2 &> proc2.out
```

Now if you want to monitor the output of one of processes, use the tail command with the 'follow' option:

```
$ tail -f proc1.out
```

If you want to see output from both processes simultaneously on stdout, use:

```
$ tail -f proc1.out -f proc2.out
```